# How should one abstract tracking code?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, logging, architecture, google-analytics

I'm working on a heavy e-commerce app. In such apps tracking is a huge concern. It's crucial to know if users use feature x or click on button y etc.

For instance let's say you can bring up the search either by clicking on a search button on the header or by a app wide keyboard command `CTRL + S`.

Now if we want to track such things, how would be the best way to handle it. I ponder and dither between (using pseudo `JavaScript` here but the language doesn't really matter):

**1. Just do the tracking directly where the action happens:**

```
function searchButtonClicked{
    //this event will be raised anyway to be catched somewhere else to bring up the search
    raiseEvent('searchButtonClicked');
    //now directly track the stuff here
    trackingService.trackEvent('searchButtonClicked');
}
```

And...

**2. Just raise events for the actions and then catch those in the trackingService**

```
function searchButtonClicked{
    //this event will be raised anyway to be catched somewhere else to bring up the search
    raiseEvent('searchButtonClicked');
}
```

...and somewhere in trackingService

```
onEvent('searchButtonClicked', function(){
   track('searchButtonClicked');
});
```

So on first glance **2.** seems a bit nicer to me as none of the components need a dependency against the `trackingService`. They don't even know that tracking exist. In addition some of the existing events can probably be reused. However that only helds true for a small subset of events. Most events would be raised more or less exclusively for the sake of tracking. So I wonder if that layer of abstraction is really necessary?

Such tracking doesn't seem to be much different from logging and I think it's accepted practice to directly log at the places where the events happen, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, it depends on your specific case.
If, like you say, most trackable operations in your application don't raise an event, then an abstraction using events is not the best option.
you could just have your code call the tracking directly, which is not the most clean thing, but it's the simplest, and if each call is just one line, as above, is probably acceptable.

I can just suggest one more little thing- you could try [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).
depending on the technology you use, you could, either-
1. Mark certain classes / methods for tracking (maybe using attributes, or whatever) OR
2. Create a class that would hold the list of all the classes / methods to track.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in JavaScript, using some library like JQuery can make your life easier. Otherwise you need to have a event registration and listener mechanism in your code.

check [here](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) of examples under bind() function

```
$( "#searchButton" ).bind( "click", function() {
  track('searchButtonClicked');
})
```